# Why are tag synonyms so hard to suggest and vote for?

Tags: discussion

I haven't paid much attention to tag synonyms before, but today I notice there's one question tagged [blend-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blend-words), and three tagged [portmanteau-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portmanteau-words).

I thought I'd do something useful and propose that these two should be merged, but it turns out I can't, because I haven't scored sufficient rep on either of the tags - hardly surprising, since I've not even voted on any of the questions, but why should that be taken to imply I'm not qualified to know that *blend-words* and *portmanteau-words* mean exactly the same thing?

Apparently I *did* have enough rep against the [suffix] tag to not even notice this as a problem when I [proposed making [suffixes] a synonym][3]. But seeing that page just confuses me even more. That proposal has been there nearly a month now, and there are still only 3 votes - one short of the required 4 to action it. Presumably everyone would want to vote that synonym through, but they can't, because they don't have enough "relevant" rep.

---

This isn't strictly part of what I'm asking/ranting about above, but I also note that the synonym [term](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term) <- [terms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terms) was apparently proposed several months ago, and is sitting in some status called "merge". I don't know what "merge" means, but I must say both tags seem undesirable to me (or at least, they should both be synonyms of [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests)). Given there's only one question tagged [term](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term), and none at all for [terms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terms), I don't understand what's going on there at all.

Comment: I see what you mean about the [term] tag: I just tried to suggest it as a synonym of [single-word-requests] (in which tag I *certainly* have gracious plenty rep), but it said I can't, because [term] has already been suggested as a synonym of [terms]; except that as far as I can tell, the [terms] tag doesn't exist.

Comment: @Martha: When I put in a request on MSO to [allow mods to blacklist unwanted tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125812/), the first commenter said the current system for synonymizing doesn't work. Incidentally, I can't see that request coming to anything - the only answer, which has quite a few upvotes, is from [Valued Associate Rebecca Chernoff](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff), basically saying proper control of tag management is too sensitive/difficult for anyone except TPTB (so why do they let boneheads create rubbish we can't tidy up?).

Comment: +1 Related: [Could mods catalyze synonym voting?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2510/10041)  It's impossible to publicize this topic too much; it needs attention!

Comment: Having a score for a tag doesn't mean voting for questions using that tag. Having a score for a tag means getting up-votes for answers given to questions using that tag.